# CodeIgniter - Severity: Notice - Message: Undefined index

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

Trying to display results of a simple query.

**[EDIT]** I think my query is problematic, there seems to be a conflict between `activitati.denumire` and `proiecte.denumire`, but I don't know how to work around that.

**Model:**

```
public function getActivities() {
    $this->db->select('idA');
    $this->db->select('activitati.denumire');
    $this->db->select('tascuri');
    $this->db->select('activitati.bugetFolosit');
    $this->db->select('proiecte.denumire');
    $this->db->select('proiecte.bugetAlocat');
    $this->db->from('activitati');
    $this->db->from('proiecte');
    $this->db->where('activitati.aprobat = 0');
    $this->db->where('activitati.idProiect = proiecte.idProiect ');

    $result = $this->db->get();
    $data = $result->result_array();

    return $data;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php


class ApproveActivity extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index () {
        $this->getData();
    }

    public function getData () {
        $this->load->model("db_Activities");
        $data['query'] = $this->db_Activities->getActivities();
        $this->loadView($data);
    }

    public function approve () {

    }


    public function loadView ($data) {
        $this->load->view("ViewActivityApproval",$data);
    }
}

?>
```

**View:**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Denumire</th>
        <th>Tascuri</th>
        <th>Buget Folosit</th>
        <th>Proiect: Denumire</th>
        <th>Proiect: Buget Alocat</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        var_dump($query);
        foreach ($query as $row): ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['idA'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['activitati.denumire'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['tascuri'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['activitati.bugetFolosit'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['proiecte.denumire'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['proiecte.bugetAlocat'];?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Strange part is: `idA` and `tascuri` work just fine, the rest don't.

I also did a `var_dump($query)` and i got a two dimensional array:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(5) { 
        ["idA"]=> string(2) "12" 
        ["denumire"]=> string(6) "Test 1" 
        ["tascuri"]=> string(11) "bla bla bla" 
        ["bugetFolosit"]=> string(3) "200" 
        ["bugetAlocat"]=> string(4) "2500" } 
    [1]=> array(5) { 
        ["idA"]=> string(2) "13" 
        ["denumire"]=> string(6) "Test 2" 
        ["tascuri"]=> string(11) "CursStiinta" 
        ["bugetFolosit"]=> string(3) "200" 
        ["bugetAlocat"]=> string(3) "100" } 
}
```

Yet `idA` and `tascuri` worked even when I had a single `foreach`. Any idea ?

Comment: I don't see `activitati.denumire` element in the array. You've output `var_dump` of the array - could you point the `activitati.denumire` in it?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you are looking for matches an index in the `$row` array other than `idA` and `tascuri`. You have it here pretty clearly - each row has elements at `idA`, `denumire`, `tascuri`, `bugetFolosit`, and `bugetAlocat` but you're looking for `activitati.denumire`, etc, which aren't indeces in the `$row` array, hence the error.

You should be doing `echo $row['denumire'];`. Why are you trying to access `$row['activitati.denumire']`??

Comment: because I have two 'denumire' or at the very least I should, as you can see in my query: `$this->db->select('proiecte.denumire');` and `$this->db->select('proiecte.bugetAlocat');`

Comment: I meant `$this->db->select('proiecte.denumire');` and `$this->db->select('activitati.denumire');`

Comment: Right, but what you use in your SQL syntax is different from what shows up in the results array. Unless you explicitly say "SELECT proiecte.denumire AS `proiecte.denumire", which I'm not entirely sure you can do anyway, the you will just get the column names in your results array, not the table names + the column names.

Comment: Regarding your above edit, you can use "AS" to alias columns so they aren't ambiguous.